# How does Eclipse identify instance variables/fields in the source code of a method?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, static-analysis

As shown in the picture, Eclipse automatically colors the instance variables/fields in their source code. 
[image]

How did Eclipse do that from an implementation perspective?

I want to try to statically do that without using Eclipse. For example, given a method, my program will be able to return a list of instance variable/field names that appeared in the method (either accessed or modified).

Comment: Please post code as text not an image, cheers.

Comment: Code on here doesn't show up the color as eclipse does... That's why I posted a picture instead of actual code, and the actual code doesn't actually have anything to do with the question rather than just showing how eclipse colored the instance variables blue.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense.

Comment: A Java parser produces a syntax tree which contains both fields, method parameters and variables. Using scoping rules variable names that are not declared as such in scope but found as fields in the current file or superclass are highlighted. Which part of that is mysterious to you?

Comment: Read about the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)